# Does web_set_timeout() is specific to a Transaction?

Tags: loadrunner

I have to use a timeout of 10 seconds for a web services script. (web services protocol)
Do I need to specify the `web_set_timeout()` function before each transaction or
mentioning at the begining of the script will apply for all transactions present in the script?

Answer (score 1):

`web_set_timeout()` will apply to all subsequent code (i.e. all the transactions that will follow the `web_set_timeout` call)

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the reply,In web_set_timeout documentaion "Resolve"  Action is not mentioned ,is there any specific reson for that?

Comment: Are you the same person as this: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/How-web-set-timeout-works/m-p/6697690#M11807